# How to install msvcr71.dll correctly

Tags: dll, windows-server-2003

how do i install msvcr71.dll on windows server 2003, which is needed by my software. I really don't want to copy this dll to system32 folder, because it may break this target system.

Answer (score 1):

Just copy it into the folder where all the executables of your program will be. It's standard practice. Searching for libraries starts from the directory where the requesting executable is located, so unless LoadLibraryEx() with LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH is used this will work allright.

Answer (score -1):

Don't copy the .dll to the System32 folder.  And if it's not already in the application's folder, then don't copy it there either! (Doing so would prevent you from getting security updates, and patches from Microsoft).  Instead, just install the [Microsoft Visual C++ 2003 Redistributable (which is included in the .NET 1.1 Runtime)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596167/where-to-download-microsoft-visual-c-2003-redistributable/6132093#6132093).