# Where to download Microsoft Visual c++ 2003 redistributable

Tags: dll, visual-c++, runtime, visual-studio-2003, redistributable

I have an old dll that uses the Microsoft Visual C++ 2003 (7.1) run time package.  Unfortunately I don't have that DLL around anymore.  Short of reinstalling VS2003, is there another way to get the run time redistributable dll?

Comment: reference: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326922

Answer (score 62, accepted):

shartte's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1596181/533832) is not correct.

The Visual C++ 2003 runtime was not available as a separate download because it was included with the .NET 1.1 runtime.

If you install the .NET 1.1 runtime you will get msvcr71.dll installed, and in addition added to C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322.

The .NET 1.1 runtime is available here: https://web.archive.org/web/20210517233454/http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26 (23.1 MB)

If you are looking for a file that ends with a "P" such as msvcp71.dll, this indicates that your file was compiled against a C++ runtime (as opposed to a C runtime), in some situations I noticed these files were only installed when I installed the full SDK.  If you need one of these files, you may need to install the full .NET 1.1 SDK as well, which is available here: https://web.archive.org/web/20210625111546/https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16217 (106.2 MB)

After installing the SDK I now have both msvcr71.dll and msvcp71.dll in my System32 folder, and the application I'm trying to run (boomerang c++ decompiler) works fine without any missing DLL errors.

Also on a side note: be VERY aware of the difference between a Hotfix Update and a Regular Update.  As noted in the linked KB932298 download (linked below by Storm): "Please be aware this Hotfix has not gone through full Microsoft product regression testing nor has it been tested in combination with other Hotfixes."

Hotfixes are NOT meant for general users, but rather users who are facing a very specific problem.  As described in the article only install that Hotfix if you are have having specific daylight savings time issues with the rules that changed in 2007. -- Likely this was a pre-release for customers who "just couldn't wait" for the official update (probably for some business critical application) -- for regular users Windows Update should be all you need.

Comment: msvcp71 is the C++ runtime (msvcr71 is the C runtime). Neither is a debug version.

Comment: I stand corrected, I saw it needed the /MD flag and had assumed the D was for debug -- it's apparently for dynamic (as in, it needs a dll file, derp.)  Good catch!

Though, what's weird, is in my tests, when I installed the .NET 1.1 runtime I didn't get the C++ stuff, but when I installed the SDK I did... hmmm...

Comment: for me, the 1.1 .NET framework installer placed the msvcr71.dll file only at ```C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322```, and did not alter path. I had to manually copy the file into ```C:\Windows\System32\``` directory for the file to be found

Comment: For whatever reason, having msvcr71.dll in C:\windows\system32 wasn't good enough for my application (Redland's rapper.exe), and I had to copy it into that application's folder.

Answer (score 12):

After a bit of googling, it seems that there never was a separate redistributable for Visual C++ 2003 (7.1). At least that is what [a post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/f6220619-3999-4489-ba5f-09d38dfaefcf) on the microsoft forum says.

You may however be able to extract the runtime DLLs from the VC 7.1 DST [timezone update](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/KB932298/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=762).

Comment: I wasn't able to extract the runtime DLLs from that update, but you are correct in that there doesn't seem to be a redistributable.  Seems like a oversight to me.

Comment: to extract the old .exe, open a commandbox and add "/xp:c:\temp\ex.msp" to the commandline of the .exe. this extracts the msp which you can open with 7-zip and extract the cab contents

Answer (score 1):

the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/6132093/1498669 is right.

There is also an update to both 2002 and 2003 runtimes
just do an search on microsoft download

- https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/search?q=mfc70
- https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/search?q=mfc71

and you find the offical updates to the products

however, the latest patches seem to be:

- https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3644
- https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22539
- https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6818

Answer (score -1):

Another way:

using Unofficial (Full Size: 26.1 MB) VC++ All in one that contained your needed files:

http://www.wincert.net/forum/topic/9790-aio-microsoft-visual-bcfj-redistributable-x86x64/

OR (Smallest 5.10 MB) Microsoft Visual Basic/C++ Runtimes 1.1.1 RePacked Here:

http://www.wincert.net/forum/topic/9794-bonus-microsoft-visual-basicc-runtimes-111/

Comment: It seems those resources are unavailable.

Answer (score -8):

I think this is what you're looking for:  [Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=9b2da534-3e03-4391-8a4d-074b9f2bc1bf&displaylang=en)

Comment: The question was about VC 2003 (msvcr7.x). I think the nice redistributable packages available for newer versions, such as your link, are not now and have never been available for the older version in the question.