# Installation issue pycrypto-2.6 on Windows 8

Tags: python, windows, pycrypto

Not sure what I'm doing wrong but when I run `pycrypto-2.6.win-amd64-py3.3.exe` I get Python 3.3 is required, which I have just installed before I tried to install the crypto. I should also note that I have VS 2013 installed, as I'm reading that I may need to compile the whole thing or something.

Anyway, as an option I have a Fedora installed on a Virtual Box, not sure how use it though but if it is "easier" on Fedora I can try to install it there.

I'm actively searching for a solution but am short on time and would like some help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably installed 32bit version of Python - install 64bit version.
`pycrypto-2.6.win-amd64-py3.3.exe` is binary package which means it's already compiled so you don't need compiler to install it. If compilation were needed you would have to have the same version of Visual C++ which was used to build Python itself; in case of the *official* Python 3.3 that's Visual C++ 2010 not 2013. See [What version of Visual Studio and/or MinGW do I need to build extension modules for a given version of Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12028762/95735) question for more details.

Comment: I would think that a 32-bit would not install. Anyway uninstalled it and installed `Python 3.3.2 Windows X86-64 MSI Installer (Windows AMD64 / Intel 64 / X86-64 binary [1] -- does not include source)`. After which pycrypto installed without issues. Thanks for your post!