# Missing MFC71.DLL for new empty VC++ Console Project

Tags: c++, dll

I am trying to get an slightly older project running again. I used the code last summer just fine. Unfortunately I did not keep the VC++ project files, just the code. As such I created a new VC++ console project and selected the "empty project" option in the process. Upon adding the code and pointing the compiler and linker to the appropriate folder I compile successfully. From there I attempt to debug and receive the message

```
The program can't start because MFC71.DLL is missing from your
computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.
```

From what I see this DLL is in the Visual Studio .NET 2003 which as far as I can tell my project should have no dependency on. I am using a robotics simulation library called callisto which I suppose could depend on it. However that project seems to be gone so I can't confirm as much from the project website. How does one go about using MS development tools to determine as much? In the event that it does not, what other possible reasons would a new project depend on such an old DLL?

Comment: "I am using a robotics simulation library called callisto which I suppose could depend on it" - check the dependencies of this library using Dependency Walker (assuming that you are using that library in form of DLL as well)

Comment: Download this .exe file and drag-n-drop that DLL on it: http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Comment: That worked @LihO. I suppose the next step is to install .NET 2003.

Comment: BTW, if you submit your comment as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if you are using that library in form of DLL (already compiled code that internally depends on redists of VS 2003), you can verify this by using the Dependency Walker (it is a simple .exe file that you can download here: http://www.dependencywalker.com/ and just drag-n-drop this DLL on it).

Also note that you don't need to install whole Visual Studio. Redistributable package for VS 2003 will do.

***EDIT***: *"The Visual C++ 2003 runtime was not available as a seperate download"* ~ check [Where to download Microsoft Visual c++ 2003 redistributable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1596167/1168156)