# Msvcr71.dll Msvcp71.dll missing

Tags: .net, windows, dll

I have wrote some application.

But when i run it on several operating systems we are getting those two files missing.

When i add them to the windows\system32 folder the application works fine.

I saw this solution  [how-to-install-msvcr71-dll-correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650982/how-to-install-msvcr71-dll-correctly) but is there any way to make

my application to use more updated version of the files that come with the latest .net

distribution.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As was mentioned in the post you link to, use whichever version of the files work for you and distribute them with your application.
Those are the VC++ dll's, not .Net.

Answer (score 0):

As BlueRaja said these are not .NET, still in order to distribute them you need to add the VC runtime merge modules to your installation (see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235290(VS.80).aspx) link).

Microsoft merge modules are provided with Microsoft Visual Studio .NET. Their default installation location is [ProgramFilesFolder]\Common Files\Merge Modules.

Additionally you may download a number of Microsoft and vendor provided merge modules at [InstallSite.org](http://InstallSite.org).

Answer (score 0):

When you create a project, if you have this option avaliable, instead of using *shared DLL* use **static library** in the options. Because the shared DLL tells your .exe or dll that it will depend on client, if he does not has the dependencies your program will fail. The static library way, the codes that your program depend will be inside the .exe or .dll that you compile.